# Checking remote port status in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, networking, scripting

I need check port on the remote server in bash script before script will continue.
I search here and on the internet, but I can´t find answer which works for me.

I´m using RHEL 7.2 virtual machine so I don´t have `-z` parameter in `nc` command or `/dev/tcp/` thing.
Also `nc remote.host.com 1284 < /dev/null` don´t work, because every time I get exit code 1.

Basically I need something like that:

```sh
/bin/someting host port

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "Great, remote port is ready."
else
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `nc host.com 1234 < /dev/null` works fine for me.  It returns `0` or `1`, depending on connectivity status.  Do you have `nmap`?  How about `nmap --open -p<port> <host> | grep -q " open "`?

Comment: With RHEL7 you can use /dev/tcp. It is not visible with `ls` command.

Comment: @Cyrus: Don´t work for me:  
    `$ /dev/tcp/google.com/80  
    -bash: /dev/tcp/google.com/80: No such file or directory`  


@eddiem:  
    `nc remote_server 1313 < /dev/null ; echo $?  
    Ncat: Connection reset by peer.  
    1`  
    `nc remote_server 1477 < /dev/null ; echo $?  
    Ncat: Connection timed out.  
    1`

Comment: It is not visible at all. Check this: `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80; echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n" >&3; cat <&3`

Comment: @Rohlik you need to prefix the command with the `: ` shell builtin. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about nmap?

```
SERVER=google.com
PORT=443
state=`nmap -p $PORT $SERVER | grep "$PORT" | grep open`
if [ -z "$state" ]; then
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT has failed"
else
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT was successful"
  exit 1
fi
```

Please note You have to install nmap.

```
yum install nmap #Centos/RHEL
apt-get install nmap #Debian/Ubuntu
```

Our you can compile and install from [source](https://github.com/nmap/nmap).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Bash itself, using it's built-in /dev/tcp device file.
The following will throw a connection refused message if a port is closed.

`: </dev/tcp/remote.host.com/1284`

Can be scripted like this:

`(: </dev/tcp/remote.host.com/1284) &>/dev/null && echo "OPEN" || echo "CLOSED"`

Details of `/dev/tcp` in bash reference manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: Thx for your reply. I tried your solution, but this command have very long timeout - 2+ minutes.

Comment: Yes thats true, you can precede it with the `timeout` command to make it finish sooner.